Coleman/York Furnace 7 red flashes after few minutes - Only on Startup
My furnace FG9C08016UP11C (horizontal) seems to be starting sometimes and not other.
As the technician suggested, I ordered, and asked him to replace the flame sensor, gas valve, flame roll-out and also the high limit controls. The ignition surface gets hot and red and that's the one not replaced that yet. The furnace works sometimes and not on a cold morning. If it works once without any hiccups to the desired temperature, it continues to work the whole day and even the next day morning. When it is quiet for a long time (a day), it again has a starting trouble.
I thought it is working fine when the panel is open and not when it is closed. Wondering if it is starving for oxygen, I cleaned the intake and exhaust pipes too, to rule out any clogs. One can hear the inducer going on, and the flame comes up, and the relay switches for gas. But there will be no flame, and after 3 attempts it gives up. It worked yesterday and this morning it worked for 30 minutes, and again the diode started to blink 7 times.
Wonder what else could be wrong..... Appreciate any help, thoughts, please. Thank you

The intarwebs says bad igniter, dirty flame sensor, and no gas flow.  You replaced the flame sensor, but not yet the igniter.  Have you confirmed gas flow?

Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the late response. I thought initially that it is the gas pressure. Apparently it works sometimes and not other. For example it worked for a week after I posted this. And again the problem started this morning. Its more of electronics than mechanical, I guess and I have replaced the new wireless Honeywell thermostat with the old Honeywell panel based settings and it is running now. I hope the board doesn't go bad that easily. Fingers crossed. Thank you
